# How to get war to use different jar version than application container's?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, solr, openshift

I'm trying to install Solr on OpenShift, deploying the vanilla Solr war.  I've got it mostly working, but logging is throwing a NoSuchMethodError exception b/c Solr is trying to use JBoss's version 1.2.14 of log4j instead of the 1.2.16 that Solr needs (both are loaded, however).

I've already adjusted the catalina.properties (common.loader) to get 1.2.16 loaded, but I don't know how to say "solr.war should use log4j-1.2.16", either explictly, or by changing some precedence or ordering of jar loading.   Because of OpenShift write restrictions, I can't just upgrade the JBoss version to 1.2.16 (and I doubt I should).

Is there...
a) a configuration change I can make to make the war use a specific loaded jar?
b) should I package the whole thing as an ear file? (I don't know much about that)
c) should I be trying to use Maven to build and configure all of this for me?  If so, how do I get started?

Comment: This is a classloader issue if you have both jars loaded. You need to get a reference to the classloader with the correct jar in and load your class with it.

Comment: which version of jboss are you using?

Comment: JBoss EWS 2.0 , as per my OpenShift install.

Answer (score 0):

You can rsync files from

`{solr_code_base}/examples/lib/ext/`

to

`$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/solrhome/lib`

In your local repo, add the below path

```
common.loader=...,/var/lib/openshift/{#id}/app-root/data/solrhome/lib/*.jar
```

(replace {#id} with your openshift user id)

in `.openshift/config/catalina.properties` and push the changes to openshift.

and copy `{solr_code_base}/example/resources/log4j.properties` file to `.openshift/config/`

It worked for me

Comment: I did that for all of the jars, including log4j-1.2.16.  However, Tomcat still uses 1.2.14.  I to somehow give my versions higher priority.

Comment: Even if you add 1.2.16 in lib?

Comment: Yep, doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Did you try this https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Getting_Started_Guide/logging.log4j.properties.html